# Jquery UI Sortable - Div scroll issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I created a Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnncs/103/).

**Code:**

//Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#panel").sortable({
        items: ".content",
        axis:"y",
        scroll:true,
    }).disableSelection();

});
```

//HTML

```
<ul id="panel" class="scroll">
    <li class="content" style="background-color:red">item1</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:green">item2</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:blue">item3</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:gray">item4</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:yellow">item5</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:green">item6</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:yellow">item7</li>
    <li class="content" style="background-color:red">item8</li>    
</ul>
```

//CSS

```
.scroll{
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    position:relative;
}
.content{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In that,When i drag the any box towards down ,it scrolls very long and move out of other boxes.
But when i drag any box towards up, it works correctly.

So, is there any way to prevent it from scrolling down long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your style sheet like this:

```
.scroll {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: static;
    width: 150px;
}
```

And use this code upper of your `ul`:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:150px;height:200px;position:relative">
```

Comment: But the Draggable item moves out of box(<ul>).

Answer (score 1):

this isn't much help, but if you check jQuery UI [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), you'll see that the problem occurs there as well.
I'm assuming it's a bug.